# Slick not able to load MySQL driver

Tags: scala, slick, typesafe-activator, typesafe

I have been following official [documentation](https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.1.0/introduction.html) following along with Activator Hello Slick 3.1, using MySQL instead of H2. With correct driver in dependency, slick can't find the driver class when running the test code. What could I be doing wrong here?

Here is my application.conf

```
mydb = {
  driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver",
  url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hello_java?serverTimezone=UTC",
  user = "nilu",
  password = "password",
  connectionPool = disabled
}
```

Here is code calling config (note the code is from Activator Hello Slick 3.1, I just replaced the driver component to connect to MySQL rather than h2:

```
import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._

object HelloSlick extends App {
  val db = Database.forConfig("mydb")
....
```

Here is my build.sbt, as you can see, I have driver in dependency.

```
libraryDependencies ++= List(
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.3.2",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.7.10",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "6.0.6",
)
```

I am getting following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Comment: Can you try `driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"`?  It's possible that `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` was introduced in a later version of the `mysql-connector-java` driver.

Comment: which `scala` version? on `2.12.10` it compiles and runs